# Get Sharepoint server name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I'm working on application where I need to upload some files in Sharepoint. Now, from what I can see when I'm accessing Sharepoint is that my url is in this format:

https://mysharepointurl.sharepoint.com/

But in the examples I'm seeing online my server needs to have URL such as 
http://servername/

where can I get that server name in the Sharepoint portal?

Comment: "sharepoint portal" do you mean the admin center ?

Answer (score 0):

The shorter path you're seeing in the instructions are referencing an on-premise installations of SharePoint.

You can map a drive to SharePoint Online to upload some files, but it takes a few steps.

1. Add the SharePoint site to the IE trusted sites list.
2. Login to the site but make sure to check 'keep me logged in'.
3. Open an admin command prompt and type the below, replacing the drive letter and tenant information as required:

   ```
   net use S:\ https://tenant.sharepoint.com
   ```